# VBA equivalent of DATEVALUE?

Tags: excel, vba

The formula function of =DATEVALUE and VBA's DateValue() provide exclusive results. How can I format a date in VBA to obtain the same serialization as I would by using =DATEVALUE?

**Example:** `1/19/2016`, formatted "m/d/yyyy", will return `42388` through `=DATEVALUE()`

Comment: I just tested both of them on a valid date string. Both returned the same results. You could try `Format('date_string',"mm-dd-yyyy")` for example.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I failed to clarify; by serialization I mean something along the lines of how the date `1/19/2016` would become `42388`.

Comment: Just change the NumberFormat of the target cell to `"General"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I need a means of doing a conversion from within the macro editor; cells cannot be altered.

Comment: In vba: `Range("A1") = "1/1/2016"` then `Range("A1").NumberValue = "General"`

Comment: @ScottCraner I think the point is that the value needs to be used in VBA and not directly in a cell. While this can get the result it means editing cells when they don't really need to be edited.

Comment: @Brad then no conversion is needed, excel will use the value of the date behind the scenes not the text of the date. **edit** if the date is a true date and not text that looks like a date.

Comment: @ScottCraner it's not clear what the end game is here but I assume they're using that date-as-a-number value for something else and have not elaborated fully here. Seems like a possible XY problem if that's the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CLng` e.g.

```
=DATEVALUE("7/7/16")
```

Returns

```
42558
```

In VBA:

```
? CLng(DateValue("7/7/16"))
 42558
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to do this. @Robin has a good one. I'll add one more

```
?DateDiff("d",0, "7/7/16")
42558
```

The [`DateDiff`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) function calculates the difference between the two dates (2nd and 3rd parameters) in the units of the first parameter. So if you changed `"d"` to `"h"` you would get the number of hours between 0 (the first possible date in Excel/VBA) and `7/7/2016`